# Automatic conversion of <i> to <svg> tag leads to ignored CSS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, font-awesome

I've been using this (https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar) article  to set up a sidebar for a web application I'm building. I'm relatively new to web development so what seem like quirks to me might be common knowledge. I'm trying to adapt the stylesheet and in doing so want to change  elements. However, none of the adjustment I make seem to work. When I inspect element in the browser, both firefox and chrome, the `<i>` line actually has been commented out and replaced with an `<svg>` tag. This then leads to the CSS not being applicable to that particular element. If I pre-emptively write CSS instructions for svg elements it works, but this seems like the wrong approach. Can someone explain to me why this automatic commenting happens and what I can do about it?

Comment: Can you provide part of the code that is having problem.

Comment: All the code I use is in the link I provided. Even before I make any adjustments to it, the `<i>` tag gets commented out and turns it into `<svg>` instead, I just want to know why this happens and what to do about it.

Comment: Here (https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/sidebar/index4.html#) a demo is provided, when inspecting the code you'll see `<!-- <i class="fas fa-copy"></i> -->`. Which is not the way it is shown in the source code. I find the same behavior when I run the code on my own server.

Comment: Seems like font awesome does it automatically. Use font awesome CSS instead of js.